# saving a nonexistent domain to a js variable in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to save to a js variable whenever a user navigates to a nonexistent website, example: http://ieatonly9timesaday.biz/

"ieatonly9timesaday.biz" is still displayed in the chrome url bar, but the actual url via

```
document.location.pathname
```

is "text/html,chromewebdata"

So, how can I grab the string of the nonexistent url that is still in the omnibox?

or alternatively, how can I parse that same url from the error message in my js console which reads:

```
GET http://ieatonly9timesaday.biz/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: may be possible using a chrome extension - although `save to a js variable` sounds like an exercise in futility

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the behavior you describe. Try `var loc = location.href`. This seems to work.

Comment: @JaromandaX I hope not :/

Comment: Also depends on dsn settings with isp. Some isp's intercept failed domains

Comment: @colecmc really? hmm, I get the same "data:text/html,chromewebdata" value for loc